# What it mean to be write heavy in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I am kind of confused in terms of what it means to be write heavy in cassandra. Is this relative to the read frequency on a particular cluster or something absolute.
e.g lets say in our environment if we have like 500 tps written and may be 100 queries per second.
In this case write is relatively higher then the reads. But if we look at  just the writes from cassandra perspective, is this really high ?

We have ssd in prod with around 64 gigs of ram.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writes are much faster and the defaults are tuned around data models that write more than they read for denormalizing the data.

4k writes/sec per core kinda standard rule of thumb which is safe (per host). With big host like that if tuned correctly its perfectly reasonable to have ~100k-200k writes a sec (if dont run outta disk). When you introduce reads that drops significantly but its really a factor of data model and the client, it should be relatively easy to do 20k a sec with 50% reads/writes but it can definitely go higher.  With a bad data model though its all out the window.

If your doing below 1k reads+writes a sec per host you shouldn't have many issues unless your data model is an anti pattern, and even then with that load it might work out.

Comment: Thanks chris. i am trying to find a good compaction strategy for our use case. In our use case we update rows many times and we also have ttl defined on table level. I looked at time series but we cant guarantee that the updates will happen within a give time window. So i was looking at  level tiered, which supposedly is good when you have updates. However its io bound and will affect the writes. everywhere i read it says its not good for write heavy workload. So thats what i am trying to find out if we are really write heavy for level tiered compaction. do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Dont worry about it with ssds, use leveled compaction. It should be the default imho. If your using update (updating same partitions that is) heavy STCS will end up performing far far far worse.